# Java remove non numeric characters from string except x

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to remove all non numeric characters from string except for x. I'm a little confused.

my current code

```
number.replaceAll("[^\\d\\x]", "")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All that is wrong with your regex is that you are unnecessarily escaping the x.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

use this: `[^x0-9]`

You may check it on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: I forgot to specify capital x as well, so would this be okay [^xX0-9]? Thanks Nurlan.

Answer (score 7):

Your regex is

```
number.replaceAll("[^\\dxX]+", "");
```

No need to escape normal characters inside a character class. An improvement is also to have the quantifier `+` after the character class, that way sequences of those characters are replaced at once and not each char on its own.

Read some regex basics on *Xisb*: [What absolutely every Programmer should know about regular expressions](http://blog.xisb.de/?p=4)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, maybe there's a better way to do it though.

```
number.replaceAll("[^\\d+xX]", "");
```

Comment: @George - Why use the plus sign?  Wouldn't that cause plusses to get skipped?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
number.replaceAll("[\\D&&[^x]]", "")
```